# Excel and Oracle SQL Connection

Tags: oracle, excel, connections

I am connecting to an Oracle DB and return data with Excel 2010. I have setup the connection in my workbook and my connection string looks as follows,

`Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=jasonpc;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=jasonpc;Data Source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))";Extended Properties=True`

I am pulling data from a table called `TBLPRICES` and the connection properties form looks like this,

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the password is saved but everytime i refresh the data i get the following popup, asking for a password.

[image]

But when this popup appears, the password is already in the password text box and when i press ok, then the data refresh. But as far as i understand when you save the password in the connection properties then the OraOLEDB Logon box should not appear. What can i do to make the logon box not to appear when i refresh the data. Is there certain settings that i need to tweak or check?